# Tools/solutions for visualization of molecular simulation trajectories?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, visualization

I have so far been using [VMD](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/) to create visualizations of molecular trajectories. However, I find myself not entirely satisfied with the quality of the resulting animations—when you want to do snapshot-by-snapshot movies, the simulation "moves" too quickly.

Additionally, I sometimes receive individual graphics images, and need to convert those into an animation. Since I worked on OS X, I've tried both [imageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) and more recently the built-in [iMovie](http://download.cnet.com/Apple-iMovie/3000-2170_4-7469.html). However, I'd like more flexibility in the available movie formats than imageMagick provides, and more command-line interface control than iMovie offers.

So, what I'd like to know is, are there other visualization tools that can either:

- given a MD trajectory, can produce the snapshots and an animation of the complete trajectory with more control provided than VMD; *or*
- given a set of snapshots (in TGA, TIFF, PNG, etc.), can produce animations in multiple formats (MPEG, M4V, etc.)?

Comment: For a similar, but not duplicate, question, see http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/898/how-do-i-create-an-animation-from-a-2d-model-or-dataset.

Comment: Hi aeismail, I just thought I'd let you know that [Chemistry.SE](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) has launched into public beta, and has a nice core of molecular simulation users…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) for movies from stills. I found this to be better than imovie and imageMagick. Just makes sure on the mac you grab the right codecs (don't remember off hand which I needed to get things working) and restart your computer after install them. Also, ffmpeg is available on [macports](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/multimedia/ffmpeg/Portfile) if that's your thing.

Don't know much about molecular dynamics visulization, but you could look into [VisIT](https://wci.llnl.gov/codes/visit/). It has some molecular dynamics support according to the [FAQ](https://wci.llnl.gov/codes/visit/FAQ.html), and the developers are pretty responsive and helpful if you need that.

Comment: +1, Based on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ffmpeg) listing the output formats supported (presumably with the appropriate codecs installed), this answer appears to answer the second question well. (Don't know about answering the first one, because I know nothing about MD.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to become a real movie star, you should check: http://www.molecularmovies.com/

For the snapshots thing you can play with mpeg encoder